How should phonetic symbol "tilted t" be pronounced?

The phonetic symbols for the first and second words' "t" are different from the "t" in the third word. What is the difference? How should the tilted "t" be pronounced?

Judging from the italic r in foremost, this means that pronouncing the /t/ (or the r) is optional.

Where are these from? I assume @PeterShor is right, but resources like this invariably include some sort of reference explaining all the symbols used.

Thanks. Words 'intimate' and 'costly' also have 'tilted t'. Then can I pronounce them /inimit/ and /kɔ́ːsli/ ?

I've never heard anyone say inimate for intimate (except maybe if they're paralytic drunk). But as a BrE speaker I'd normally replace the second /t/ by a glottal stop ɂ. And on rare occasions I might also replace the first /t/ likewise.

Like @FumbleFingers, I've never heard /inimit/ for intimate (and I'm from the U.S.). But the /t/ is indeed optional in postpone, postwar, and costly, as is the /r/ in foremost, so I'd guess that is what it means.

Please give us the name of the dictionay. And, if possible,  a link too. Thanks :)

@Araucaria - Him This book is an English dictionary made in Korea. There may be a foreign dictionary that the publisher of this book has referred to, but it doesn't seem to be cited. As many say, it is probably italic, or tilted phonetic symbols, that mean omitable. However, it seems right to conclude that some words, such as intimate, seem to be pronounced as they are without people omitting them.

@EunjinPark What is the name of the dictionary?

The dictionary should have a guide to its pronunciation. If it does not, I suggest that you get one that does.
If we compare the OED's pronunciation guide, we have
Postpone -> British English /pəˈspəʊn/ puh-SPOHN - elided
Postwar -> British English /pəʊs(t)ˈwɔː/ pohsst-WOR - de-emphasised
foremost -> British English /ˈfɔːmə(ʊ)st/ FOR-mohsst -> unemphasised
In all cases, the "t" is de-emphasised to some degree. I assume this is the purpose of the italic "t".

In the OP's example, the /t/ in "foremost" isn't tilted.
